# Adding google analytics tracking to my iOS Today Widget

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8-today-widget, google-analytics-sdk

I have in my widget a few buttons and I want to track clicks.

Is this possible or even allowed by Apple? I'm have been looking for information but can't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple. In the navigator panel of your containing app  select libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a file and in File Inspector check it for your extension target:
[image: File Inspector]

I did it for libAdIdAccess.a too and for all frameworks needed for GA:

- CoreData.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libz.dylib
- libsqlite3.dylib
- libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Next go to *viewDidLoad* of your Widget ViewController and do an ordinarily implementation for GA SDK: import headers, init tracker, send events.
You can immediately check how it work in Real-Time section of GA interface.

Comment: I get a warning: "linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions" but it appears to be working

Comment: To configure an app extension target to use an embedded framework, set the target’s “Require Only App-Extension-Safe API” build setting to Yes. If you don’t, Xcode reminds you to do so by displaying the warning “linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions”.

Comment: Thanks FreeGor! It was set to YES but changing to NO removed the warning

Comment: Has anyone had any experience with using the same tracking ID for both the iOS app and its extension? Is there a risk in doing so?

Comment: @Ricky I do not think there is any risk, but why mix it? This can affect the statistics of launching applications events, users sessions, etc.

Comment: @FreeGor Good point, I didn't consider that, especially launch. I have ~18 apps with extensions so was trying to avoid creating new tracking IDs.

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to the answer from @FreeGor. Tracker in the Widget Controller should be initialized using:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXX-XX"];
```

in order to send properly events to GA